# PHP Array Nominal Indexes with Strings

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP application that takes a CSV in input; in the first column I have both category and subcategory splitted by a '|'. I have to put this stuff in a Open Cart DB, which has the same table for Category and Subcategory (a column "parent_id" indicates the category_id of the Category).
I thought to build a class with all the fields needed as follows:

```
class Categorie {
    public $category_id;
    public $parent_id;
    public $image;
    public $top;
    public $column;
    public $sort_order;
    public $status;
    public $date_modified;
    public $date_added;
    public $language_id;
    public $name;
    public $description;
    public $meta_description;
    public $meta_keywords;
}
```

Then I analyze the data:

```
$categorie = array();
while ( ( $riga_file = fgetcsv( $file, 100000, "\t" ) ) !== false )
{
     $array_el = count( $riga_file );
     for( $el_cur = 0; $el_cur < $array_el; $el_cur++ )
     {
         switch ( $el_cur )
         {
             case 0:
             $colonne = explode( "|", $riga_file[$el_corr] );
             $categoria = new Categorie();
             $categoria->image = "";
             $categoria->top = 1;
             $categoria->column = 1;
             // ... bla adding description data
             if( $categorie[$colonne[0]] == NULL ) // (1)
             {
                 $categoria->name = $colonne[0];
                 $categoria->category_id = $id_categoria;
                 $categoria->parent_id = 0;
                 $categorie[$colonne[0]] = $categoria;
                 $id_categoria++;
             }
             if( $colonne[1] != NULL ) // (2)
             {
                 $categoria->name = $colonne[1];
                 if( $categorie[$colonne[1]] == NULL )
                 {
                     $categoria->category_id = $id_categoria;
                     $categoria->parent_id = $categorie[$colonne[0]]->category_id;
                     $categorie[$colonne[1]] = $categorie;
                     $id_categoria++;
                 }
             }
             break;
         }
```

I should have an array filled with a collection of unique objects like:

```
  // OUT(3)
  Category 1
  Subcategory 1
  Category 2
  Subcategory 2...
```

If I put echoes of $categoria (not $categorie) inside (1) and (2), I see exactly what I wrote down in OUT(3), which leads me to think that my "engine" is correct. The problems come when I try to search into the array:

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
            foreach( $categorie as $value )
            {
                echo "<tr>
                           <td>$value->category_id</td>
                           <td>$value->parent_id</td>
                           <td>$value->name</td>
                      </tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
```

because I don't get Categories at all, and most but not all Subcategories.
Am I doing something wrong with "search engine" or I misunderstood something with PHP Arrays (probably because I come from C++ and this php is f**king my mind)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, or better: problems.

1) I mispelled a variable: in (2) I wrote:

```
$categorie[$colonne[1]] = $categorie;
```

The correct writing is:

```
$categorie[$colonne[1]] = $categoria;
```

2) The bigger problem was from my "unknowing" of PHP, in fact, fixed the problem 1, I got an output like:

```
subcategory1
subcategory1
subcategory2
subcategory2
```

and so on. This lead me to guess that when I do:

```
$categorie[$colonne[1]] = $categoria;
```

PHP doesn't copy the values inside, but uses addresses instead. Follows the right code:

```
switch ( $el_corr )
                    {
                        case 0:                                                 // Categorie e sottocategorie
                            $colonne = explode( "|", $riga_file[$el_corr] );
                            $categoria = new Categorie();
                            $categoria->image = "";
                            $categoria->top = 1;
                            $categoria->column = 1;
                            $categoria->sort_order = 0;
                            $categoria->status = 1;
                            // Category_Description Campi
                            $categoria->language_id = 1;
                            $categoria->name = $colonne[0];
                            $categoria->description = "";
                            $categoria->meta_description = "";
                            $categoria->meta_keywords = "";
                            ////////////////////////
                            if( $categorie[$colonne[0]] == NULL )
                            //if( !trova_categorie( $colonne[0], $categorie ) )
                            {
                                $categoria->name = $colonne[0];
                                $categoria->category_id = $id_categoria;
                                $categoria->parent_id = 0;
                                $categorie[$colonne[0]] = $categoria;
                                $id_categoria++;
                            }
                            $categoria = new Categorie();
                            $categoria->image = "";
                            $categoria->top = 1;
                            $categoria->column = 1;
                            $categoria->sort_order = 0;
                            $categoria->status = 1;
                            // Category_Description Campi
                            $categoria->language_id = 1;
                            $categoria->name = $colonne[0];
                            $categoria->description = "";
                            $categoria->meta_description = "";
                            $categoria->meta_keywords = "";
                            if( $colonne[1] != NULL )
                            {
                                $categoria->name = $colonne[1];
                                if( $categorie[$colonne[1]] == NULL )
                                //if( !trova_categorie( $colonne[1], $categorie ) )
                                {
                                    $categoria->category_id = $id_categoria;
                                    $categoria->parent_id = $categorie[$colonne[0]]->category_id;
                                    $categorie[$colonne[1]] = $categoria;
                                    $id_categoria++;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
```